# add dictionary as columns to a dataframe (only one column)

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe and a Dictionary so I need to add the column "area" (only one) from the Dict. matching the names,but only "area" not the others.

Code:

```
df["area"] =df["name"].map(dict["area"])
```

[image: Dictionary]
[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post pictures. Just show your dictionary and dataframe as code. and your desired output also as code.

Comment: please edit your question to include your data as text for easy copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the .str accessor, [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas-series-str-get) or [[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings), to access keys in a dictionary:

```
df['area'] = df['name'].map(d).str['area']
```

I recommend changing variable name of your dictionary from, dict to something else.  Here, I assume your dictionary is stored in variable, d.